# Is someone stealing (halachically) if he re-uses a coupon code intended for single use?

Tags: halacha, gezel-stealing

A take-out place near me has a coupon code that gives you $10 off a minimum $15 order if you are a first-time registrant through "Seamless", a food ordering app.

Technically, the code is supposed to be used only for the 1st order. However, one could get around this system indefinitely by creating a new email address and using a different credit card for each order.

Despite the procedure, above, being civilly legal (in NY State, at least), would this still be considered stealing or a violation of some other halacha?

**Additional info (if relevant)** - AFAIK, "Seamless" is not owned by Jews. The take-out place that I order from is. However, when paying for the order, the takeout place gets the full price of the order, not the discounted price. Seamless "absorbs" the remaining cost.

Comment: It seems like gneivas da'as to me, sidestepping the intent by hiding behind the letter of the law, thus taking money from the store through that artifice.

Comment: @DanF , Can you explain how a different credit card would allow a second use? A new email address can easily be created for free; (minus a small amount of time of course) but a credit card in one's wallet usually has the same name as the other card. Wouldn't that alert the store or coupon system to deny the code and discount? Did you mean that you could use a friend's or corporate card?

Comment: @DavidKenner - You can't identify a card by name alone. There is more than one John Smith with a card. In a country that requires the entry of an ID number associated with the card (like Israel), that could trigger a warning flag. In any case, I side with Danno, and anyway don't see the point in setting up another card just for this. There are too many cards in most peoples pockets as it is.

Comment: @Danno apparently, Seamless cares more about the card number than the email address, as that's what it uses for payment, obviously. Also, the email address is used as your login name, so, you need a new email address. However, a different email address with a different credit card number makes Seamless think this is a different customer. Epicenter is correct - apparently, Seamless does not do that thorough an identity check on initial registration.

Comment: 1. Why would it not be considered stealing? 2. Since when is stealing from non-jews allowed? 3. There's also the Chillul Hashem aspect of cheating the system, if you can get around the first 2 issues.

Comment: @DannySchoemann "Chillul Hashem" from my understanding, is based largely on other people's perception. In most cases. that involves something visible, though, not a necessary requirement, of course. Point is, in this case, Seamless, doesn't know what's happening, as they consider the reuse a new registration from a different person. The Chilul Hashem, perhaps, would be in what Hashem knows is happening. Depends if that comes under the definition of Chilul Hashem, anyway. It's a different problem, perhaps.

Comment: @DanF - based in recent news coverage, these  things tend to become known eventually and then create a Chillul Hashem in all senses of the word. "Rabbis re-use coupon codes" says the headline.

Comment: @DannySchoemann Got the idea. BTW, you've seen this headline in the Israeli papers? I thought rabbis don't use the internet, except when they're advertising a mass public event about not being allowed to use the internet :-)

Comment: http://rabbisblog.brsonline.org/just-permissible-doesnt-mean-right/

Comment: @GershonGold Have to read the entire article a bit later. You live in Boca, or you chanced on this article? FYI, while my main question focused on stealing, since I asked if there were other halachic problems, this may form an answer, anyway.

Comment: Chanced upon the article. Live in NJ. Felt it may help towards an answer.

Comment: @GershonGold No Jersey jokes other than that your governor is, so far, being a bit humbled in the polls. Too bad ;-( I miss him & Trump arguing who's the bigger loser.

Comment: The only reason I haven't written an answer is that I'm not 100% sure it's _stealing_ as opposed to _misleading_ (Ona'a) which is permissible if the _sucker_ is non-Jerwish.

Comment: @DannySchoemann For the most part, the "sucker" is a web site.

Comment: @DanF - Somebody owns that web-site. Still self-debating the  _stealing_ vs. _misleading_ question.

Answer (score 2):

**Valid emails**
The point of their discount is to collect valid email addresses.

So as long as one uses a valid email address, i.e. one that is read, it should be OK.

They are more than happy to have you read their promotional emails more than once.

**Unread email addresses**
Once you use email addresses that you never read (like disposable ones) then you have to keep in mind various Halachot.

1. **Chilul Hashem**; if your behaviour is unbecoming - and lots of Yidden do this shtick - then it could cause a "Yidden rip off Seamless" headline and accompanying Chillul Hashem.
2. If you're in a location where this is illegal, then it's forbidden because of **Dina D'Malchusa**; the law of the land has to be followed - especially in monetary issues.
3. As to the stealing issue: It would depend if this behaviour is considered that you are stealing or you are simply taking advantage of a loophole they didn't close.

   - **Stealing** - even from non-Jews - is forbidden.
   - Taking advantage of their ignorance (if no Chillul Hashem is involved) is permitted.

I imagine a [lawyer](https://law.stackexchange.com/) could answer that.

Some Sources from the Kitzur Shulchan Aruch:

[סימן סג - אסור להונות בדברים ולגנב דעת הבריות](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00561.html#HtmpReportNum0062_L2)

> **סעיף ד'**: אָסוּר לִגְנֹב דַּעַת הַבְּרִיּוֹת (פֵּרוּשׁ לְרַמּוֹת בִּדְבָרִים, אַף עַל פִּי שֶׁאֵין בּוֹ חֶסְרוֹן מָמוֹן), אֲ**פִלּוּ דַּעַת עוֹבֵד כּוֹכָבִים**. וְלָכֵן אָסוּר לִמְכֹּר לוֹ בְּשַׂר נְבֵלָה בְּחֶזְקַת שְׁחוּטָה. אִם מוֹכֵר אֵיזֶה דָּבָר שֶׁיֵּשׁ בּוֹ מוּם, אַף עַל פִּי שֶׁהַדָּבָר שָׁוֶה כְּמוֹ שֶׁהוּא מוֹכְרוֹ לוֹ, מִכָּל מָקוֹם צָרִיךְ לְהוֹדִיעַ לְהַלּוֹקֵחַ אֶת הַמּוּם (וְעַיֵּן לְקַמָּן סִימָן קפ"ב סָעִיף ד') (וּבְמַתָּנָה לֵכָּא מִשּׁוּם גְּנֵבַת דַּעַת). ‏

[סימן קפב - הלכות גנבה וגזלה](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00561.html#HtmpReportNum0181_L2)

> **סעיף א'**: אָסוּר לִגְזוֹל אוֹ לִגְנוֹב אֲפִלּוּ כָּל שֶׁהוּא, בֵּין מִיִשְֹרָאֵל **בֵּין מִגּוֹי**. ‏
>
> **סעיף ד'**: אָסוּר **לַעֲשׂק** אֶת חֲבֵרוֹ אֲפִלּוּ כָּל שֶׁהוּא, שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר, לֹא תַעֲשׂק אֶת רֵעֲךָ. וְאֵיזֶהוּ עושֵׁק. זֶה שֶׁבָּא מָמוֹן חֲבֵרוֹ לְיָדוֹ בִּרְצוֹן חֲבֵרוֹ, כְּגוֹן שֶׁיֵשׁ לוֹ בְיָדוֹ הַלְוָאָה אוֹ שְׂכִירוּת, וְאֵינוֹ רוֹצֶה לְשַׁלֵּם לוֹ, אוֹ שֶׁדּוֹחֵהוּ בְּלֵךְ וָשׁוּב, לֵךְ וָשׁוּב. וְכֵיוָן דִּכְתִיב רֵעֲךָ, **אֵינוֹ אָסוּר בַּגּוֹי**. וְהוּא **שֶׁאֵין חִלוּל הַשֵּׁם בַּדָּבָר**, כְּגוֹן שֶׁלָּוָה מִגּוֹי וָמֵת, רַשַׁאי לְכַחֵשׁ לִבְנוֹ, שֶׁאֵינוֹ יוֹדֵעַ בְּבֵרוּר שֶׁהוּא מְשַׁקֵּר. אֲבָל **כְּשֶׁהַגּוֹי יוֹדֵעַ שֶׁהוּא מְשַּׁקֵּר, אָסוּר**, מִפְּנֵי **חִלוּל הַשֵּׁם**. וְאַף בְּמָקוֹם שֶׁאֵינוֹ יוֹדֵעַ, אֵינוֹ רַשַׁאי אֶלָּא לְהַפְקִיעַ הַלְוָאָתוֹ אוֹ שְׁאָר חוֹב שֶׁהוּא חַיָב לוֹ. אֲבָל חֵפֶץ שֶׁהוּא בְעָיִן, אָסוּר לִכְפֹּר, שֶׁהֲרֵי זֶה הֲוֵי גָזֵל מַמָּשׁ. וְלֹא עוֹד, אֶלָּא אֲפִלּוּ קָנָה מִמֶּנוּ חֵפֶץ, **אָסוּר לְהַטְעוֹת אוֹתוֹ בְּחֶשְׁבּוֹן בִּנְתִינַת הַמָּעוֹת**, כְּמוֹ שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר, וְחִשַּׁב עִם קוֹנֵהוּ, דְּמַיְרֵי בַּגּוֹי, שֶׁהֲרֵי אֵינוֹ מַקְנֶה לוֹ הַחֵפֶץ אֶלָּא בְּעַד הַסְּכוּם שֶהִשְׁתַּוּוּ. וְהַמַּטְעֵהוּ בְּחֶשְׁבּוֹן הַמָּעוֹת, הֲרֵי זֶה כְּגוֹנֵב אֶת הַחֵפֶץ וְלֹא כְּמַפְקִיעַ חוֹבוֹ. וַאֲפִלּוּ **גְנֵבַת דַּעַת שֶׁאֵין בָּהּ חֶסְרוֹן מָעוֹת, אָסוּר בְּמַשָּׂא וּמַתָּן**, כְּמוֹ שֶׁכָּתַבְתִּי בְסִימָן סג. וּמִכָּל מָקוֹם אִם הַגּוֹי טָעָה בְעַצְמוֹ, מֻתָּר אִם לֹא יִהְיֶה חִלוּל הַשֵׁם בַּדָּבָר, שֶׁלֹּא יִוָּדַע לוֹ. וְנָכוֹן שֶׁיֹּאמַר לוֹ הַיִשְֹרָאֵל, רְאֵה שֶעַל חֶשְׁבּוֹנְךָ אֲנִי סוֹמֵךְ.‏

Comment: Thanks for the research and thorough answer. Offhand, this seems like a question of "ignorance", but that's my own take on it, which, I admit, is biased, since I'm the one doing it. Looks like I'll need a rav or another opinion / analysis on this. I'm sure that this scenario has occurred numerous times before.